# Is there a way to restrict apps access to my Evernote?

Tags: evernote

When I give an app access to my Evernote account, can I say, "only access XYZ notebook" or "you only have the right to write, but not to read, my notes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams Evernote at the time of writing has no support for [OATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiative_For_Open_Authentication) like many others do. :(

The only way at the moment to give a 3rd party access to your notes is to give it your password. If you give your password to a 3rd party they will have the same access rights to your Evernote as you have. This is true for any other service.

**UPDATE: I was wrong! I could link my Evernote account to [Greplin](https://www.greplin.com/) without giving them my password. In Evernote it appeared under Settings -> Authorized services. So Evernote does support a form of OATH or can give 3rd parties access to their API without revealing your password to them.**